# Cakephp 2.x PayPal notify URL not working

Tags: php, cakephp, paypal

Hi i am tried to solve my problem. Unable to solve that so i need your help.

I have download the the PayPal script from http://code.google.com/p/paypal-ipn-class-php/downloads/list
I got 2 files there are `paypal_class.php` and other file is `paypal.php`

I have copied and paste the paypal_class.php file to `Vendor/Paypal/paypal_class.php`.

I have calling the `paypal_class.php` file in my paypal action. The `App::import('Vendor', 'Paypal/paypal_class');` is working fine in my `UsersController.php` file.

Please check my code:

**test.ctp**

```
<form name="paypal" id="paypal" method="post" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="chinmay235-facilitator@gmail.com" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Purchase Gold Coin" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" id="amount" value="50" />
    <input type="hidden" name="image_url" value="http://dev.raddyx.com/finalgame7/img/logo.png" />
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://dev.raddyx.com/finalgame7/users/mycoin" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://dev.raddyx.com/finalgame7/users/mycoin" />
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" id="notify_url" value="http://dev.raddyx.com/finalgame7/users/paypal" />
</form>
```

**UserController.php**

```
public function paypal(){


App::import('Vendor', 'Paypal/paypal_class');
$p = new paypal_class();
if (empty($_GET['action'])) $_GET['action'] = 'process';  

    switch($_GET['action']) 
    {
        case 'process': 
        //Process email here...
        break;

        case 'success':
        //Success email here...
        break;

        case 'cancel':
        //Cancel email here...
        break;

        case 'ipn':         

        if($p->validate_ipn())
        {
            //Payment Success complete email here...
        }
        exit;
    }

}
```

Above i have used 4 test email but i did not get any email..

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I know to debug and test remote server notification is to make good use of Logs.

So your `paypal()` function should be full of log statements, tracking the code path that is being followed and dumping various variable values so you get a sense of what is going on in your code.

You can manually trigger the IPN call by vising this link:

(http://dev.raddyx.com/finalgame7/users/paypal)

This will just show you if your controller is working or not. Then you need to use the PayPal IPN tester (it's somewhere in PayPal's developer center).

Once you have your logs and you have an idea of what is going on come back with a more specific question, if things are still not working.

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add the file name in "notify_url"

Currently it is:

input type="hidden" name="notify_url" id="notify_url" value="http://dev.raddyx.com/finalgame7/users/paypal" />

But It should be like:

input type="hidden" name="notify_url" id="notify_url" value="http://dev.raddyx.com/finalgame7/users/paypal/**notifying_filename.php**" />

Comment: Hello @Faisal Alvi This is cakephp not core php